# HtmlAgilityPack SelectNode doesn't works on WP8.1

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-8.1, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

On my console project, it's works great...but when i make it on windows phone 8.1, it does not work. What's the problem?

```
HtmlNodeCollection NoAltElements = HD.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='f2p-card']//div[@class='champion-info']//a[@href]");


HtmlNodeCollection NoAltElements = HD.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='white-stone']//a[@href]");
```

Comment: This is Q&A site, what is the question here? And make sure it is [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to be asked here

Comment: as i said, im trying to make  .SelectsNodes() on WP8.1, but cant understand how can i do this if XPath doesnt support on WP8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "im trying to make .SelectsNodes() on WP8.1, but cant understand how can i do this if XPath doesnt support on WP8.1"

Common alternative when HtmlAgilityPack (HAP) XPath API not available is LINQ API, for example :

```
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> NoAltElements =
                        HD.DocumentNode
                          .Descendants("div")
                          .Where(o => o.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "f2p-card")
                          .SelectMany(o => o.Descendants("div"))
                          .Where(o => o.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "champion-info")
                          .SelectMany(o => o.Descendants("a"))
                          .Where(o => o.GetAttributeValue("href", null) != null);

IEnumerable<HtmlNode> NoAltElements = 
                        HD.DocumentNode
                          .Descendants("div")
                          .Where(o => o .GetAttributeValue("class","") == "white-stone")
                          .SelectMany(o => o.Descendants("a"))
                          .Where(o => o .GetAttributeValue("href",null) != null);
```

Comment: i got a problem on the screen [link](https://pp.vk.me/c627425/v627425110/a921/swamBz0kc28.jpg)